# Python 2.7: set variable name

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to set the variable name in a for loop, like:

```
for i in range(5):
    namei = i # this is a variable name
```

It will give me:

```
name0 = 0
name1 = 1
name2 = 2
name3 = 3
name4 = 4
```

does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: You can modify `locals()` and `globals()` in some cases. If the containing scope is a module, there are valid reasons to do so, though arguably `getattr/setattr` are preferred. If it's your class, feel free to hack it either way you like. If it's a function, the only way other than `locals()` is to go through `foo.func_code.co_nlocals/co_varnames/co_consts` but you'd need to crate a new function on the fly. **in short** if you are not sure, use a data structure instead: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having 5 separate variables, you should use an array.

Eg.

```
name = [] #Create an empty array

for i in range(5):
    name.append(i) #Add each value to your array
```

This will leave you with

```
name[0] = 0
name[1] = 1
...
etc.
```